# Received unknown parameter: stripe_account

Tags: php, stripe-payments

I am trying to perform a Stripe payment_intent for a Connect Custom account. But I get this error:

```
Received unknown parameter: stripe_account
```

My code snippet is:

```
public function add_order_amount( &$args, $order, $amount = null ) {
        $args['amount'] = wc_stripe_add_number_precision( $amount ? $amount : $order->get_total(), $order->get_currency() );
        $monto = wc_stripe_add_number_precision( $amount ? $amount : $order->get_total(), $order->get_currency() );
        $args['application_fee_amount'] = round( ($monto * 0.01) + 0.30) ;  // 1% + 0.3 USD
        $args['stripe_account'] = 'acct_1L2zW6PuKflLQEIm';
    }
```

Comment: It does not look like a typical PHP error, is it perhaps generated by your own code somewhere? Are you sure the exception is thrown in this function (perhaps a stack trace is available)?

Answer (score 2):

There is no parameter called `stripe_account` in Stripe's API. Usually, this refers to a separate feature called the `Stripe-Account` header (see [doc](https://stripe.com/docs/connect/authentication#authentication-via-the-stripe-account-header)) which allows you to make requests on behalf of a connected account.

This means you shouldn't be passing the connected account id this way. Instead, you should be setting the connected account as a request header.

You haven't provided much context on your integration but you seem to be using a WooCommerce plugin and they might have a way to configure the connected account such as [this function](https://docs.paymentplugins.com/wc-stripe/api/source-class-WC_Stripe_Account_Settings.html#22-27). Otherwise you'll have to modify the code making the HTTP request to set your own `Stripe-Account` header